# htaccess route only if no other parameter in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

i trie to rout from the mainfolder of my subdomain (wildcard) to the content-folder for the specific sub-domnain.

So i trie

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.tld$
    RewriteRule ^$ %1/ [L,NC]
```

If i test it with http://example.domain.tld

It will rout to the "example" folder.

But i cannot access the files inside the folder. therefor i have to change the url by hand to example.domain.tld/example/antotherfile.html

Also if i test with http://example.domain.tld/anotherfile.html it failed completly.

What i do wrong?

Another trie with this code failed completly

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]*)\.domain\.tld$
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1 [L]
```

After two days of running about that i'm not closer to the goal :-(

Comment: 404page not found, yes if iadd the subfolder manually to the url i can access

Comment: thereis not much more, ive update the two lines in head of htaccess file. Maybe i have to put a second htaccess file inside the subdomain folder (example)?

Comment: with this i get a redirection-error. In url is http://test.domain.tld/test/test/test/test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* %1/$0 [L]
```

Comment: :-)) at the first look it seems to work, whats the big magic about that?

Comment: It is `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` condition that rewrites it only once.